# GWT JSON cross-site request fails

Tags: javascript, json, gwt, jsonp

imo i did everything according to the tutorial here [Googles x-site](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html)

```
    /**
   * Make call to remote server.
   */
  public native static void getJson(int requestId, String url,
      StockWatcher handler) /*-{
   var callback = "callback" + requestId;

   // [1] Create a script element.
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.setAttribute("src", url+callback);
   script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

   // [2] Define the callback function on the window object.
   window[callback] = function(jsonObj) {
   // [3]
     handler.@com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher::handleJsonResponse(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)(jsonObj);
     window[callback + "done"] = true;
   }

   // [4] JSON download has 1-second timeout.
   setTimeout(function() {
     if (!window[callback + "done"]) {
       handler.@com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher::handleJsonResponse(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)(null);
     }

     // [5] Cleanup. Remove script and callback elements.
     document.body.removeChild(script);
     delete window[callback];
     delete window[callback + "done"];
   }, 1000);

   // [6] Attach the script element to the document body.
   document.body.appendChild(script);
  }-*/;
```

but it keeps failing me.. all other methos are also written.. i just can understand why it tells me every time that "Couldn't retrieve JSON"  (it tells that when handler's input is null)

btw i am talking about the "3. Requesting the data from the remote server" on the googles site

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using [`JsonpRequestBuilder`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html), instead of all this JSNI code - no JSNI code (maybe just some overlay types), easier to debug, etc.

```
 String url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full" +
     "?alt=json-in-script";
 JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder(); // No JSNI!
 jsonp.requestObject(url,
     new AsyncCallback<Feed>() { // Type-safe!
       public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
         // Easy to debug! (hopefully)
       }

       public void onSuccess(Feed feed) {
         // Success!
         }
       }
     });
```

Comment: i tried it.
for static files it worked, but in case of a dynamic json files it always failed.
any ideas?

Comment: Are *you* responsible for generating the JSON files on the server side? Then maybe it's a bug :D (no offence ;)) Either way, try downloading the dynamic and static files via browser or wget and compare and validate them: http://www.jsonlint.com/ is a great JSON validator. Also: "it always failed" - could you be more specific as to how it "failed"? :D